# Incorrect Expiry Date for an inapp subscription while using Google Play Developer Api

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In my Android application I'm tracking the subscription status of a purchase made with google play store inapp. And I'm using the Google Play Developer api in order to retrieve the autorenewal status and expiry date of transaction.

The problem is that, the response is not showing the exact expiry date, not even a more close value to the desired expiry date. The subscription is actually annually renewing one. I've configured the subscription in such a manner that it renews every one year. But, when I'm tracking the status of a particular user with Google Play Developer api and Purchase token it shows expiry date which is 31 days in length instead of the expected 365 days.

```
Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_SubscriptionPurchase Object(
[internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[autoRenewing] => 1
[expiryTimeMillis] => 1468777228126
[kind] => androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase
[startTimeMillis] => 1466089483565
[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
        [priceCurrencyCode] => GBP
        [priceAmountMicros] => 14990000
        [countryCode] => GB
        [developerPayload] => 
        [paymentState] => 1
    )

[processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

All other details obtained from response such as price, currency etc. are same as that of I configured in the console. Why I'm not getting the expiry date with one year duration for one-year subscription product?

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.